# Cannot create a photo album using Aiogram 3.x and MediaGroupBuilder

Tags: python, bots, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm working on a function in a Telegram bot in Python, using the Aiogram3.x library, that should create a photo album from the received photos in a message and send it to users. However, even though the code executes without errors, the album is not created and the photos are not sent as expected. Here is the part of the code responsible for creating the album:

```
async def get_all_photo_ids(message):
    # Assuming message.photo is a list of photo sizes, and you want the largest one
    photo_ids = []

    # If message.photo contains multiple sizes, select the largest one based on file_size
    for photo_size in message.photo:
        # The largest photo is the one with the maximum file_size attribute
        largest_photo = max(message.photo, key=lambda x: x.file_size)
        photo_ids.append(largest_photo.file_id) # Assuming each 'photo' is a list or similar iterable
    return photo_ids

@dp.message(SpamState.waiting_for_spam_text)
async def send_spam(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    with sqlite3.connect('Active.db') as conn:
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute("SELECT user_id FROM active_users")
        users = curs.fetchall()

    if message.photo:
        photo_ids = await get_all_photo_ids(message)  # Get all photo IDs

        # Initialize variables
        media_group = MediaGroupBuilder()
        unique_photos = {}  # No need for set as you have photo_ids directly

        # Iterate through photo IDs
        for photo_id in photo_ids:
            unique_photos[photo_id] = unique_photos.get(photo_id, 0) + 1
            media_group.add_photo(media=photo_id)

        caption = message.caption if message.caption else None

        # Send photos/album based on count
        if len(unique_photos) == 1 or all(count == 1 for count in unique_photos.values()):
            for user_id in users:
                await bot.send_photo(chat_id=user_id[0], photo=next(iter(unique_photos)), caption=caption)
        else:
            for user_id in users:
                await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=user_id[0], media=media_group.build())
```

Could you please suggest what I'm doing wrong or what I need to change to get the album formed and sent correctly?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.